# Redirect not working for Pages and Posts URLs from http to https in Wordpress .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https, http-redirect

I am trying to redirect from http to https for my website. The code I use is working for home page only and redirecting properly. for example it redirects correctly from http to https

However the pages I create in my wordpress site can be accessed for both http and https for example a page can be accessed at both URLs below

http://www.example.com/any-page-url and https://www.example/any-page-url

However I want all http pages redirect to respective https pages. the htaccess file I use is

```
   # BEGIN WordPress   
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
   RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

   </IfModule>    
   # END WordPress

   RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Change permalinks in WP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try with putting your code top of htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*)https:// % {HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

If this is not works then try following code in place of your https redirect code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I just placed the redirect code on the top and the suggested codes worked like a magic.